# Telegram winapi открытие канала без браузера

Tags: c#, winapi, telegram

Всем привет, если в браузере вставить ссылку на канал https://t.me/durov, то при условии если установлен телеграм, то вы автоматически перейдете на этот канал в Десктопе. Можно ли как-то повторить трюк, но без браузера? Имея хэндл окна телеграма, может какой-то запрос отправить по winapi?

Comment: Просто откройте `tg://resolve?domain=durov` минуя браузер.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ И как это сделать минуя браузер?) А главное, если у меня по умолчанию стоит десктоп телеграм, а мне нужно открыть на Portable версии?

Comment: Библитотека wininet, например так http://forumnov.com/lofiversion/index.php?t79095.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот код должен открыть канал Дурова в установленном Telegram.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
//...
try
{
    using (Process myProcess = new Process())
    {
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "tg://resolve?domain=durov";
        myProcess.Start();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Если вам нужно запустить Телеграм из какого-то другого места, можно попробовать запустить Telegram.exe с параметрами:

```
Telegram.exe -- tg://resolve?domain=durov
```

Но этот способ я не проверял.

Comment: БЛАГОДАРЮ! Будь счастлив